# Explanation of induced E.M.F. graph when a bar magnet falls through a coil

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

When I let a bar magnet fall through a coil, I get an induced emf graph like this (this is actual data).
[image]

1. What causes the small rise before the first dip?
2. Why is the last peak broader than the one in the middle? I think it should be narrower, as the magnet is accelerating, and will take less time to fall.

Comment: What kind of coil are you using?  Its self-inductance may be substantial, which would affect your results.  Also, back reaction from the induced current on the magnet may slow it down, as in the classic [copper tube and magnet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BeFoz3Ypo4) demo;  it would be helpful to know what sort of current you're inducing, so that we could tell if this effect is important in this situation.

Comment: I am using a rectangular copper coil with the number of turns in order of 100 (not sure about the exact number). I don't understand what you mean by "current I am inducing." I am just letting the magnet fall through the coil, and measuring induced EMF.

Comment: Is the magnet coaxial with the coil or is it possible that it is rotating as it falls through (so it is going "sideways" when it is entering or leaving the coil)?

Comment: I think that the horizontal time axis runs from right to left which would show accelerated motion.

Comment: The magnet is supposed to be coaxial ( I am leaving it from 10 cm above, so don't have complete control). Also, time axis is from left to right